# How to send out current week in shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix

I need to write a shell scripts to send out every week by UNIX. I have no idea how to assign a variable in the script. Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_SUMMARY="weekly_updates.html"
WEEK_NUMBER = %V
YEAR = %Y
WORK_WEEK = YEAR.WEEK_NUMBER

echo "To:aaa@gmail.com">| $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
date "+Subject:Weekly Update - WW%U %Y">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo -e "Content-Type:text/html;charset:/"UTF-8/"">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "<!doctype html>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "<html>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "<head>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo -e "<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html";charset=\"UTF-8\">">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "</head>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "<body>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY

echo "<pre>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "I am in week $WORK_WEEK" >> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
echo "</pre>">> $OUTPUT_SUMMARY
```

The code give error that line 4,5,6 command not found which is the declare of WEEK_NUMBER, YEAR and WORK_WEEK. How to i declare the variable so i can use it in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
WEEK_NUMBER = %V
```

(with spaces) will try to run the `WEEK_NUMBER` program, passing `=` and `%V` as arguments.

What you need is what you have on the `OUTPUT_SUMMARY` line above, an assignment with *no* spaces:

```
WEEK_NUMBER=%V
```

In any case, that would simply set `WEEK_NUMBER` to the literal `%V`. Since those `%`-arguments are meant for the `date` command, you should probably use:

```
WEEK_NUMBER=$(date +%V)          # Store output of date week-no.
YEAR=$(date +%Y)                 # Store output of date year.
WORK_WEEK=${YEAR}.${WEEK_NUMBER} # Construct from variables.
```

Of course, if the *only* thing you want to use is the `WORK_WEEK` variable, it can be simplified quite a lot, as `date` allows you to insert arbitrary text into its output:

```
WORK_WEEK=$(date +%Y.%V)
```

This will also get rid of the potential bug when running your script very late on December 31st. In that case, it's possible for the week number is extracted in year `N` and the year extracted in year `N+1`. Unlikely, yes, but I'm paid to worry about such things :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 4th line of your code with:
WORK_WEEK=$(date '+Year:%Y Week:%V')